# List gets deleted after an update section occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, global-variables

I have a global variable that I'm referencing in a ASP.NET web page update panel.  Here's what happens in the update panel:

```
    accidentListType.Add(Convert.ToString(AccidentDescription.SelectedItem));
        if (Atfault.Checked)
        {
            accidentAtFault.Add("True");
        }
        else accidentAtFault.Add("False");
        DateTime newDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(accidentyear.Text), Convert.ToInt32(accidentmonth.Text), 1);
        accidentListDate.Add(newDate);
        TestAccidentLabel.Text = "Success! " + newDate.ToString();
```

Basically what happens is a list gets another added member every time a button is clicked.  But every time it runs through the code, the new index mysteriously gets deleted, so when I go to add all of the accidents to the database, there's no accidents to add.  And I can't add them dynamically, because one of the inputs to the accident database is the Identity from another table, which I pull when the table gets created, so I have to add them all after anyways.

Can anyone help?
P.S. This is my first time posting, so apologies if it's messy or anything.

Comment: Are the entry's deleted between each session? If so, where is your code that moves the data into the database?

Comment: I'm not even trying to move entries to a database here.  I'm just trying to populate a list that will go into a database eventually.  but every time I try to add a new entry, it mysteriously vanishes.  In the debug mode, I used the immediate window to see that the Count variable increments after adding, but when it exits the handler code, and I press the button again, I call the Count function to see that the Count is zero.

Comment: Are you storing accidentListType in the viewstate/session/anywhere to persist it between postbacks?

Comment: I think so.  I just did this: `Session["accidentListType"] = accidentListType` at the end of the block.  Is that right?  I'm not quite sure.  If that is right, then yes, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things that you are missing. Though your list is Global, since after every request the page object is destroyed, until and unless you keep the list in Session, the values would not persist. Also, you have to reuse the list that you have kept in session for adding any new value. Do as following.

```
//at the start of block
//check if there is anything in Session
//if not, create a new list
if(Session["accidentListType"] == null)
   accidentListType = new List<string>();
else //else a list already exists in session , use this list and add object to this list
  accidentListType = Session["accidentListType"] as List<string>;

//do your processing, as you are doing

//and at the end of bloack store the object to the session
Session["accidentListType"] = accidentListType
```

Comment: No such luck.  I tried it, but even the Session values kept getting cleared.

Comment: never mind, fixed it.  that was right.  It just kept getting re-initialized to null.  Thanks so much!